# laravel content management system

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to install this CMS https://github.com/murattanriover/basecms-laravel, I followed the install instruction, I created new database and I modified `database.php` file with my host data and I followed these instructions:

```
 composer install
 php artisan key:generate
 Create a database and inform .env
 php artisan migrate to create tables
 php artisan db:seed to populate tables
```

But when i try to run: `localhost/projectname/public/`

I got the following error:

[image]

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: there are too many ways you could do this wrong, can you clarify it a bit?

Comment: Set the debug option to true in app/config/app.php - this error could appear for any number of reasons, you need to turn debugging on to see the actual error.

Comment: Can you post an image of the error page?

Comment: @JosipIvic i made the option true and i got that error : RuntimeException in compiled.php line 6911: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Comment: @Mustafa Ehsan  http://s8.postimg.org/4all49otx/Untitled.png

Comment: @Mustafa Ehsan yes i use wamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config\app.php change:

```
'cipher' => 'something stands here(delete it)',
```

to

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to manually add the key laravel generated to your .env file.

open the console and

```
php artisan key:generate
```

then you'll get the new key

```
Application key [xlhF31NeOlibJcoOW9tvZg7TkHcAZI3a] set successfully.
```

then go to projects and

```
~/projects/ nano .env
```

Manually add the key laravel generated to your .env file

```
APP_KEY=xlhF31NeOlibJcoOW9tvZg7TkHcAZI3a
```

Comment: i can't rename the file frome .env.example to .env ??

Answer (score 2):

You need to set APP_KEY in .env

Set it to a random 32 character string
OR
Run php artisan key:generate in the root folder of your project.
This sets a random 32 character string for the encryption key.

Comment: i ran in CMD " php artisan key:generate " and i got a key i put the key at .env file and i still have the same error .

Comment: have you renamed .env.example to .env ?

Comment: no when i try to make it .env , it get me you should put a file name ?

Comment: @darknight Try to restart your **artisan server** as well.

Comment: @Mustafa Ehsan yes am using wamp and i restarted the artisan , but i can't rename the file from .env.example to .env ??

Comment: Try this [solution](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-or-key-length-are-invalid) for WAMP specific, don't forget to restart your wamp apache. If it worked, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @MustafaEhsan it works now but when i try to log in i got that error , SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please accept it as an answer or vote up. For your second problem please check your **.env** file and make sure your database connection details are fine. If it still didn't work, post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using WAMP server, please do as follow:

1. Open your wamp's **php.ini** (in my case it's in: **C:\WampDeveloper\Config\Php\php.ini**)
2. Find this line and uncomment it (remove front “;”).

   From `;extension=php_sockets.dll` to `extension=php_sockets.dll`
3. Save file. Restart Apache.
4. Do a `php artisan key:generate`.
5. Then make sure that your **config/app.php** has a line as follow:

   `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',`

[Reference to WAMP specific solution.](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-or-key-length-are-invalid)